# An element of $S$ can be written as a sum of homogeneous elements of $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> Let $F$ be a field with characteristic zero. Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL(n,F)$. Suppose $GL(n,F)$ acts on $R=F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ as follows: if $A\in GL(n,F)$ and $P\in R$, define a new polynomial $P_A$ by linear substitution. For instance, when $n=4$, $$P_A((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T)=P(A^{-1}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T)$$
>   Let $S\subseteq R$ be the ring of invariant polynomials under the action of $G$. Hence if $P\in S$ we have $P((x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T)=P(g^{-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T)$ for all $g\in G$. Show that any element of $S$ can be written as a sum of homogeneous elements in $S$. (a polynomial $P$ is a homogeneous element of degree $r$ if $P(\lambda x_1,\ldots,\lambda x_n)=\lambda^r P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$)

I know that the map $\tau:R\rightarrow R$ by $\tau(A)(P)=P_A$ is a group homomorphism. Clearly, if we let $P$ be invariant under $GL(n,F)$ then $P$ is itself homogeneous of degree $0$. But I have no clue how to prove the result if we restrict ourselves to a finite subgroup of $GL(n,F)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 0**

> $P$ is homogeneous of degree $d$ iff it can be written as a linear combination of monomials of (total) degree $d$.

**Hint 1**

> If $P$ is homogeneous of degree $d$, then so is $P_{A}$.

**Hint 2**

> If $P = P_{0} + P_{1} + \dots + P_{n}$, with each $P_{i}$ homogeneous of degree $i$, then $P_{A} = (P_{0})_{A} + (P_{1})_{A} + \dots + (P_{n})_{A}$.

**See also**
[this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial).